# character sent to serial port not read by arduino

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, arduino, arduino-ide

I am sending a character from visual studio C# to the serial port and I want arduino to read the character and do some work. But, its not reading it correctly. I have tested the arduino program using the serial monitor and it is working perfectly.Here's my C# code.

```
private void startBit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char start = '!';
        byte[] buffer = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(start) };
        timerRealTimeData.Enabled = true;
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM29";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Write(buffer, 0, 1);
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {

            Start.Enabled = false;
            Stop.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Here's the arduino code for reading the serial port

```
char incomingByte;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

}
 void loop()
 {

 if(Serial.available() > 0) {

  incomingByte = Serial.read();
  if(incomingByte=='!')
      {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);

      }
  }

}
```

I am stuck on this for a long time.Any help is appreciated

Comment: **Be more specific with your problem description**. "It doesn't work" or, in this case, "it's not reading it correctly" tells us pretty much nothing about your issue other than the fact that it just doesn't work. Which we assume is the case because of the post's existence in the first place.

Comment: Becouse you are new here, do not forget to mark as accepted the answer that satisfy your question. We have thousands of unanswerd questions only because people forget to to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the equivalent Ascii (33) using an int instead of a char. Also change the line

```
if(Serial.available() > 0)
```

To

```
if(Serial.available())
```

Some reference for you. [Here](http://bildr.org/2011/01/arduino-serial/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a function where you open the serial port, and a function where you close the serial port. Your click handler startBit_Click opens the serial port, which means that if the handler is called again, the port is already open and an exception will be generated. (unless you have other code not shown that closes the serial port?)

Second, I am guessing you are connected to the arduino through the USB port?
If so, DtrEnable should be false (default), as you have no XON/XOFF software handshaking.

You should also examine the buffer in the debug window, set a breakpoint after the buffer is assigned the character and check that the character you send is indeed what you think it is.